# How to cancel all animations except of a specific one in Android studio

Tags: android

I have my code here and my problem is that I wish to have just one specific animation active when an if condition is satisfied. 
You can see over my code that for doing this I need to separately close all the other animations in order to achieve my goal.

I want to know if is a clean way of doing this.

```
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2000,20000);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override

            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
                    int number = nearestBeacon.getMajor();

                  if(number == 1479)
                    {
                        Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.test);
                        blueButton.startAnimation(an);
                        yellowButton.clearAnimation();
                        blueButton2.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton2.clearAnimation();
                        purpleButton.clearAnimation();
                        redButton.clearAnimation();
                        greenButton.clearAnimation();


                    }

                    if(number == 7574)
                    {
                        Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.test);
                        blueButton2.startAnimation(an);
                        blueButton.clearAnimation();
                        yellowButton.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton2.clearAnimation();
                        purpleButton.clearAnimation();
                        redButton.clearAnimation();
                        greenButton.clearAnimation();


                    }
                    .
                    . 
                    .
                    if(number == 61120)
                {
                    Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.test);
                    yellowButton.startAnimation(an);
                    blueButton.clearAnimation();
                    blueButton2.clearAnimation();
                    orangeButton.clearAnimation();
                    orangeButton2.clearAnimation();
                    purpleButton.clearAnimation();
                    redButton.clearAnimation();
                    greenButton.clearAnimation();
                }



            }
        }
    });
    region = new Region("ranged region", null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `anim.cancel()`; but you should also call `anim.reset();` immediately after it. Then when you want to start it again, just call startAnimation on the view.

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately this is not working. I also tried this before but the thing is when I use startAnimation again after anim.cancel() and anim.reset() my program does not show just my desired animation but all the animations I used before together with it :)